# Why can you not "improve your English ability"?

Tags: collocation

I hear a lot of Japanese people say "I want to improve my English ability" but I can't explain why this sentence is wrong.

Could anyone tell me why you shouldn't say I want to improve my English ability" instead of "I want to improve my English"?

Comment: You can improve your ability to speak and write in English , but the  ability is just your own, not English.

Comment: @Josh61 But we would say *I want to improve my speaking ability* wouldn't we? So I think the OP poses a valid question; why not *English ability*? I think the simple answer is that it is not idiomatic (which I realise is a cop out). You could of course say *I want to improve my ability in English* - that would be idiomatic.

Comment: @WS2 - your speaking ability is your ability to speak. Your English ability is your ability to..??? English ability is just wrong, makes no sense!!

Comment: @Josh61 Your English ability = Your ability in English.

Comment: @WS2 - no, I am sorry..I don't think so!!

Comment: Thank you for helping me. You could say things like: artistic ability, musical ability or athletic ability but not "English ability" because it's not idiomatic?

Comment: Yes @ Josh61 doesn't agree with me, but I think *English* is a perfectly good adjective that can describe *ability*. It is just our idiomatic tradition which rules it out.

Comment: @WS2 I reckon you should make that an answer.

Comment: There are 'National English Ability Tests' ('English is a noun, not an adjective, in these usages). There would seem no good reason not to use 'English ability'.  BBC News at www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-28211676 has: 'Same genes "drive maths and reading ability" ...
8 Jul 2014 - ... limitation was that the authors cannot (and do not) tell us which genes are actually thought to influence children's reading and maths ability'. The premodifying _ing_-forms (swimming, footballing, cooking, knitting ...) probably sound less jarring than other attributive nouns (biology, football, chess...).

Comment: Perhaps do you want to improve your English *fluency*?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Had logic prevailed in the evolution of English we would probably be talking about *Englishing ability*, and *chessing ability* together with *footballing ability*.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not giving any logical argument/s here beyond (1) the people setting the NEATs use the collocation _English ability_, and (2) _maths ability_, as well as _reading ability_, is obviously used.

Comment: @Summer As a native speaker of English, I think *English ability* is fine, as do WS2, another native speaker and apparently also Edwin, another native speaker, who cites an analogous usage  from the BBC.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you the Chinese-language explanation :-)

> [**365 Common Chinese Errors in English**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zadylbl7hO8C&pg=PT4&dq=%22my%20English%20ability%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WX4UVaT_H4uYNvOzgJgC&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22my%20English%20ability%22&f=false) Katia Santome
>
> Don't say: I want to improve my English ability.
>
> Say: I want to improve **my English**.

One explanation:

"my English ability" can be read as "my ability at [doing] things English, whatever they/that may be" (??) :-)

I'd suggest that even:

"my **English-language ability**"

is better than "my English ability."

BTW, "to improve one's ability **in**" is idiomatic:

> [The Adult Learner](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FLlOy7sNgpwC&pg=PT218&dq=%22improve%20one%27s%20ability%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7IQUVbmaK6awsASLtoDYBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22improve%20one%27s%20ability%20in%22&f=false) Malcolm S Knowles, ‎Elwood F Holton III, ‎Richard A
> Swanson - 2012
>
> Closely related to meta-cognition or cognitive
> strategies (Weinstein and Mayer, 1986), a key element of reason's role
> in thinking is learning **to improve one's ability in** perceiving,
> analyzing, proposing, imagining, and reflecting.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it *may* be read as. Context and speaker's intention are more important than possible readings

Answer (score -1):

> I want to improve my English.

does all the work of

> I want to improve my English ability.

so the latter sounds unnaturally wordy.

Answer (score -3):

The reason saying it in that order is not quite right is because both "English" and "ability are nouns so it has to do with the order of the nouns. That's why you should say: "improve my ability with/in/at English," or simply "improve my English." Also because the word "improve" suggests one has already established a level of "ability."

Comment: So saying  _football manager_ is not quite right because you should say 'manager of [a] football [team]'?